# How to test abstract interfaces with JUnit5?

Tags: java, inheritance, testing, abstract-class, junit5

When having a set of classes that extend or implement one or more abstract interfaces, it seems just natural to implement a corresponding test helper class that can be reused for the individual test classes.

For example having an abstract class `A`, and classes `B` and `C` extending `A`, the natural approach would be to write a `TestA` class that uses dynamic binding to test methods of `A`, and then write classes `TestB` and `TestC`, each extending `TestA` (for easy use of the tests defined in `TestA`). Of course `TestB` will pass objects of type `B` to the methods of `TestA` (likewise `C` objects to class `TestC`).

However when I try to do such a thing, I only get exceptions from the JUnit5 runtime, it seems. Like this:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [java.lang.String arg0] in executable [public de.bla.utils.tests.BufferedInputStreamTest(java.lang.String)].
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameter(ExecutableInvoker.java:191)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameters(ExecutableInvoker.java:174)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameters(ExecutableInvoker.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:61)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:197)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:188)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$1(ClassTestDescriptor.java:181)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:80)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:60)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$null$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.lambda$execute$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:92)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

So, how would I organize such tests?

Comment: Add a minimal example. I don't fully understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: In order to assist you, we need to see the source code of `BufferedInputStreamTest` and its superclass (at least the fields and constructors).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is not directly related with inheritance. It seems you are declaring arguments in your test methods (type `String` concretely) without any JUnit 5 extension to support the dependency injection. I think your problem would be solved removing these arguments.

Comment: The problem is that the method with the argument is a constructor that is not tagged as @Test method. Removing that constructor makes Eclipse complain that an explicit constructor is needed. When also removing the parameterized superclass constructor, the test class ran as expected (but the tests themselves need tweaking now).